# Do i need 'unsigned' keyword with uintXX_t?

Tags: c++, c, types, unsigned

I just discovered fixed-size types which can be found in stdint.h / cstdint. Some of them are "normal" types, like int32_t and some are designed to be unsigned, like uint64_t. 
Do i need to use the "unsigned" keyword when using types which are unsigned by design ?

Comment: What happens when you try it? (I know the answer to that, but you don't and should.)

Comment: So you know uint64_t is in stdint.h, did you open this file? open it and you will understand that uint64_t is nothing but a typedef to unsigned long long int.. and if you know what typedef is you have answer to your question!

Comment: Java programmer? <g> There's nothing abnormal about unsigned types.

Comment: @Shrikant - `uint64_t` is not required to be `unsigned long long`. It can be `unsigned long` or even `unsigned` if the compiler defines that type as 64 bits wide. (I suppose it could also be `unsigned short`, but that would be pointless, because whenever you used it it would get converted to `unsigned`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to use `unsigned` and in fact, you **can not** use it.

Only the fundamental types may be modified with the `signed` and `unsigned` (also `long` and `short`) keywords.

Aliases of the standard types can not be modified using those keywords and that includes the fixed width aliases.

If you write `unsigned int32_t`, then the compiler will parse this as a variable with type `unsigned` (which is shorthand for `unsigned int`) and the name of the variable will be `int32_t`. `unsigned int32_t variable_name` would be a syntax error.